# Binary Image Classification with CNN - best practices for choosing "negative" dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Say, I want to train a CNN to detect whether an image is a car or not.

What are some best practices or methods to choosing the "Not-Car" dataset?

Because this dataset could potentially be infinite (basically anything that is not a car) - is there a guideline on how big the dataset needs to be? Should they contain objects which are very similar to cars, but are not (planes, boats, etc.)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like in all of supervised machine learning, the training set should reflect the *real distribution* that the model is going to work with. Neural network is basically a function approximator. Your actual goal is to approximate the real-world distribution, but in practice it's only possible to get the sample from it, and this sample is the *only thing* a neural network will see. For any input way outside of the training manifold, the output will be a just a guess (see also [this discussion on AI.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/92/9647)).

So when choosing a negative dataset, the first question you should answer is: *What will be the likely use-case of this model?* E.g., if you're building an app for a smartphone, then the negative sample should probably include street views, pictures of buildings and stores, people, indoor environment, etc. It's unlikely that the image from the smartphone camera will be a wild animal or abstract painting, i.e., it's an improbable input in your real distribution.

Including images that look like a positive class (trucks, airplanes, boats, etc) is a good idea, because the low-conv-layer features (edges, corners) will be very similar and it's important that the neural network learned important high-level features correctly.

In general, I'd use 5-10x more negative images that positive ones. [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) is a good starting point: out of 50000 training images 5000 are the cars, 5000 are the planes, etc. In fact, building a 10-class classifier is not a bad idea. In this case, you'll transform this CNN to a binary classifier by thresholding its certainty that the inferred class is a car. Anything that the CNN isn't certain about will be interpreted as not a car.

Answer (score 2):

I think the negative sample should be selected depend on the occasion your model works on. If your model works on the street as a car detector, the reasonable negative sample should be street road background, trees, pedestrian,and other vehicle that commone in street. So i think there is not a universal negative sample select rules but only depend on your need.